# Getting an object of a foreign key relationship to show in Django

Tags: python, django, admin

The problem occurs with this image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LteIH.png

I would like it so that the VendorProfile name instead of VendorProfile object appears in the box. I am using a foreign key relationship for PurchaseOrder in VendorProfile.
Here is my code in models.py:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')
class VendorProfile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

And here is my code in admin.py:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount', 'purchase_date','vendor', 'notes']
   list_display = ('product','vendor', 'price', 'purchase_date', 'confirmed', 'get_po_number', 'notes')
```

So how can I get it to display the VendorProfile's 'name' in both fields and list_display?

Answer (score 3):

Define a [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method for your `VendorProfile` method returning the name.

From the docs:

> The `__unicode__()` method is called whenever you call `unicode()` on an object. Django uses `unicode(obj)` (or the related function, `str(obj)`) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the `__unicode__()` method.

```
class VendorProfile(models.Model):
    # fields as above

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add a unicode function to your classes returning the value you want to show in the drop down:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.product

class VendorProfile(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=256)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

That will then show the Vendor name in the admin drop down.